# PHP Codeigniter Array Calculations

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am having a problem, which I hope someone could help me with.

I am using CodeIgniter to pull results from a database, and I would like to add these results together. I am not much of a PHP developer, so I am not too sure where to start.

This is the function I am using;

```
function get_warranty($id) {
    $this->db->select('warranty');
    $this->db->where('sID', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('cars');
    return $query->result();
}
```

This function, returns this;

```
[warranty] = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
                [warranty] => 2
            )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
                [warranty] => 5000
            )

)
```

But, I would like it to return this;

```
[warranty] = 5002;
```

So, it simply adds up each result it finds.

Any help at all, would be greatly appreciated, as I say, I'm not much of a PHP developer, so I don't even know where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $query -> result() function returns an array of objects with query results...
See documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

This is the modified function I propose, which simply returns an integer with the total sum, as you need:

```
function get_warranty($id) {

    // Query composition
    $this->db->select('warranty');
    $this->db->where('sID', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('cars');

    // Iterate through the returned objects and accumulation in $warranty 
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $warranty += $row->warranty;
    }

    return $warranty;
}
```

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

In place of `return $query->result();` use `return $query->result_array();`. You will get returned with pure array.

Now you can use foreach loop to add the values up like this:

```
$add_up = 0;
foreach ($reulst_array as $values)
{
    $addup = $add_up + $values;
}
```

This way variable `$add_up` will contain the added array.

Comment: Hi Butterfruit, thanks for your (very fast) reply, but unfortunately, I got errors with this; "Unsupported operand types", is this because $values is an array?